# Modify a query with no results in pre_get_posts

Tags: wp-query, pre-get-posts

I'm looking for a way to ensure a query always returns posts, even if the original query was empty.
The query is a custom post type archive query, and my goal is to change a query var if the query has no results.

In the `pre_get_posts` filter, `$query->have_posts()` always returns no posts, so I can't find a way to do this – is there any way to predict whether a query will have results in the `pre_get_posts` filter?

Comment: i'd say no. as the name of the action suggests (aka. pre) it runs BEFORE the query, so there are no results, yet.. so you would have to go in after the query run..

Comment: You have access to the query vars as early as [`parse_request`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/parse_request/), run the query manually and see what the results are, then you can reset things as needed.